# ssh is working abnormally on google cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

I created 5 instances on Google cloud. when I open a window ssh for one instance, it can ssh on the other instances. However, after 5 minutes, the ssh is refused giving pemission denied error. 
After, closing the window and opening it again, the ssh works normaly. However, after 5 minutes, the same issue appears.

Any suggest why this is happening?

Comment: what ssh client are you using to connect?

Comment: I am not using a client. I am using the browser window provided by google

Comment: Its probably a problem with how chrome(?) handles this, it probably doesn't expect 5 terminals open at the same time and its getting confused as to which one its supposed to be ssh'ing to. try open one of the other terminals in incognito, and see if they can talk to each other ?

Comment: i am only opening one terminal for one instance only. the others is not opened but they are working.

Comment: Google cloud make the ssh from one server to another possible for like 5 minutes. After that, the servers act as normal ones where you need to create your own private/public key between the servers. And add your key to the authorized_keys file

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud make the ssh from one server to another possible for like 5 minutes. After that, the servers act as normal ones where you need to create your own private/public key between the servers. And add your key to the authorized_keys file